# Wrapping a pure virtual method with arguments using Boost::Python

Tags: c++, python, interface, word-wrap, boost-python

I'm currently trying to expose a c++ Interface (pure virtual class) to Python using Boost::Python. The c++ interface is:

### Agent.hpp

```
#include "Tab.hpp"
class Agent
{
    virtual void start(const Tab& t) = 0;
    virtual void stop() = 0;
};
```

And, by reading the "official" tutorial, I managed to write and build the next Python wrapper:

### Agent.cpp

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <Tabl.hpp>
#include <Agent.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

struct AgentWrapper: Agent, wrapper<Agent>
{
    public:
    void start(const Tab& t)
    {
        this->get_override("start")();
    }
    void stop()
    {
        this->get_override("stop")();
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(PythonWrapper)
{
    class_<AgentWrapper, boost::noncopyable>("Agent")
        .def("start", pure_virtual(&Agent::start) )
        .def("stop", pure_virtual(&Agent::stop) )
    ;
}
```

Note that I have no problems while building it. What concerns me, though, is that as you can see AgentWrapper::start doesn't seem to pass any argument to Agent::start in:

```
void start(const Tab& t)
{
    this->get_override("start")();
}
```

How will the python wrapper know "start" recieves one argument? How can i do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The get_override functions returns an an object of type [override](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~jwicks/boost/libs/python/doc/v2/wrapper.html#override-spec) which has a number of overloads for differing number of arguments. So you should be able to just do this:

```
void start(const Tab& t)
{
    this->get_override("start")(t);
}
```

Did you try this?

Comment: I already did it that way. And it seems to work. Thanks a lot.